# Mouse-click copying Qooxdoo label text adds adjacent label text in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, qooxdoo

new to Qooxdoo here. I have a container that extends qx.ui.container.Composite that houses a Grid layout which contains basic labels in *x* rows and 4 columns. The text in columns 0 and 2 are static, whereas the text in columns 1 and 3 are dynamic.

```
this = qx.ui.container.Composite;
this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
this._labelContainer = new qx.ui.container.Composite();
this._labelContainer.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Grid(30, 3));
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("First Name:", true, false), {row: 1, column: 0});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.firstname, false, true), {row: 1, column: 1});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("Last Name:", true, false), {row: 1, column: 2});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.lastname, false, true), {row: 1, column: 3});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("County:", true, false), {row: 2, column: 0});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.address.county, false, true), {row: 2, column: 1});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("City:", true, false), {row: 2, column: 0});
this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.address.city, false, true), {row: 2, column: 1});
this.add(this._labelContainer)    

// Member function
_createLabel: function(text, bold, selectable) {
    var ret = new qx.ui.basic.Label(text);
    if (bold) ret.setFont("bold");
    if (selectable) ret.setSelectable(true);
    return ret;
}
```

**ISSUE:** When I copy the text from one label by double or triple clicking on a mouse, both the label text and the text from the adjacent label are copied to the clipboard. This copies the adjacent label text whether it is set to Selectable or not. Mouse drag/select/copy works, but that does not satisfy client requirements. I have only experienced this in Chrome ~ v63, never happens in Firefox (IE, Edge are unknowns). Qooxdoo v5.x

I've scoured everywhere (qooxdoo forums, bug reports, Chrome bug reports, SO....) and haven't run into anyone that has reported encountering this issue. Anybody else run into this issue or have any insight to share that may help the 'qooxdoo way'?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that this is just a quirk of how Chrome chooses to select text - each of those labels are separate `<div>`'s and Chrome is choosing to join them together in selection (even though there are other divs in between which are not selected).  You can select just the bits you want by clicking and moving the mouse instead of double clicking.

One thing that I would point out about your sample code however is that you should not assign a value to `this`; it looks like you are trying to write a class, but the correct way to do this in Qooxdoo would be to use `qx.Class.define(...)`.

For example:

```
qx.Class.define("my.MyClass", {
  extend: qx.ui.container.Composite,

  construct: function() {
    this.base(arguments);
    this.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
    this._labelContainer = new qx.ui.container.Composite();
    this._labelContainer.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Grid(30, 3));
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("First Name:", true, false), {row: 1, column: 0});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.firstname, false, true), {row: 1, column: 1});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("Last Name:", true, false), {row: 1, column: 2});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.lastname, false, true), {row: 1, column: 3});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("County:", true, false), {row: 2, column: 0});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.address.county, false, true), {row: 2, column: 1});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel("City:", true, false), {row: 3, column: 0});
    this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.address.city, false, true), {row: 3, column: 1});
    this.add(this._labelContainer)    
  },

  members: {
    _createLabel: function(text, bold, selectable) {
        var ret = new qx.ui.basic.Label(text);
        if (bold) ret.setFont("bold");
        if (selectable) ret.setSelectable(true);
        return ret;
    }    
  }
});

var comp = new my.MyClass();
doc.add(comp, { left: 100, top: 100 });
```

Also, when writing an example for others to look at, it is really useful to be able to sketch out your example in the Qooxdoo Playground (http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/playground/) - this allows you to give people an instant reproducable example of your problem.

Here's a playground version of your example: [Playground Example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%252F%252F%2520Create%2520a%2520button%250Avar%2520button1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522First%2520Button%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250A%250Avar%2520person%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520firstname%253A%2520%2522Peter%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520lastname%253A%2520%2522Person%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520address%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520county%253A%2520%2522Abc%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520city%253A%2520%2522Def%2522%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250A%250Aqx.Class.define(%2522my.MyClass%2522%252C%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520extend%253A%2520qx.ui.container.Composite%252C%250A%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520construct%253A%2520function()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.VBox())%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grid(30%252C%25203))%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(%2522First%2520Name%253A%2522%252C%2520true%252C%2520false)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25201%252C%2520column%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.firstname%252C%2520false%252C%2520true)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25201%252C%2520column%253A%25201%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(%2522Last%2520Name%253A%2522%252C%2520true%252C%2520false)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25201%252C%2520column%253A%25202%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.lastname%252C%2520false%252C%2520true)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25201%252C%2520column%253A%25203%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(%2522County%253A%2522%252C%2520true%252C%2520false)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25202%252C%2520column%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.address.county%252C%2520false%252C%2520true)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25202%252C%2520column%253A%25201%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(%2522City%253A%2522%252C%2520true%252C%2520false)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25203%252C%2520column%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this._labelContainer.add(this._createLabel(person.address.city%252C%2520false%252C%2520true)%252C%2520%257Brow%253A%25203%252C%2520column%253A%25201%257D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.add(this._labelContainer)%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520members%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520_createLabel%253A%2520function(text%252C%2520bold%252C%2520selectable)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520ret%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.basic.Label(text)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(bold)%2520ret.setFont(%2522bold%2522)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(selectable)%2520ret.setSelectable(true)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520ret%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520comp%2520%253D%2520new%2520my.MyClass()%253B%250Adoc.add(comp%252C%2520%257B%2520left%253A%2520100%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%2520%257D)%253B%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)